# Scala function that takes Class type as a parameter

Tags: scala, apache-spark

In scala I would like to create a function that takes as a parameter a class type.
For example:

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)
case class Order(orderId: String, amount: Int)

def readParquet(path: String): DataFrame = {
  return spark.read.parquet(path)
}

def readParquetAsDataset(path: String, MyObject: MyClassThatChange): DataFrame = {
  return readParquet(path).as[MyClassThatChange]
}
```

Finally I can do:

```
var dsProduct = readParquetAsDataset(myPath, Product)
var dsOrder = readParquetAsDataset(myPath, Order)
```

My datasets rows are casted with the good data types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass in the Encoder as an implicit.  Note your classes must be top level for the Spark productEncoder logic to find them at runtime.

Note: you don't need to use return in Scala unless you want to jump out from some piece of code's execution but that's typically something you want to avoid.

```scala
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)
case class Order(orderId: String, amount: Int)

def readParquet(path: String, spark: SparkSession): DataFrame =
  spark.read.parquet(path)

// requires a generic T with an implicit type class of Encoder[T]
// returns the typed Dataset (DataFrame is Dataset[Row])
def readParquetAsDataset[T: Encoder](path: String, spark: SparkSession): Dataset[T] = 
// as takes the implicit Encoder[T] instance
  readParquet(path, spark).as[T]

val myPath = ""
val spark: SparkSession = null

import spark.implicits._ // brings in the encoder derivation
  
var dsPerson = readParquetAsDataset[Person](myPath, spark)
var dsOrder = readParquetAsDataset[Order](myPath, spark)
```